# How to escape backslash in XAML binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I know we can use `StringFormat` to escape characters in XAML, but I am unable to understand how does it works.

I would like to escape `\` so that a string containing a path like `C:\Windows\System32` should be displayed correctly.

How can this be achieved?

**Later Edit**:

I got the following xaml:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=DownloadPath}" Header="Path" />
```

which produces the following output:

[image]

As you can see, instead of `\` it adds a `î`.

Comment: Can you please give an example of such a binding where a simple backslash does not work?

Comment: @KlausGütter I edited initial post and added an example.

Comment: This looks more like a charset encoding problem in the DownloadPath property. Can you verify e.g. using the debugger that the value of the DownloadPath property is as you expect?

Comment: The value of DownloadPath property is as expected.

Comment: I'm 100% sure that there is no need to escape characters in the value of a bound property. You have to search for some other reason.

Comment: One more test you can do: If you write `Header="A\B"`, how does the header look like?

Answer (score 0):

try to do like this. double the "\\"
"C:\\windows\\system32"

Comment: "c:\\windiws\\system32"

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. I just wanted to let you know you can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58230425/edit) your own questions, answers and comments

Comment: If the value is coming from a binded property that won't help.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you'd find any string automatically has it's single slashes replaced in visual studio. Meaning it's a bit more involved than one might first think to get a string with just one backslash in there presented to a binding.

I don't really follow how you ended up with that odd character.
So it could well be that something else is going on.

Let's narrow the problem though.

Assuming you have one single backslash, I don't think stringformat will help.

You could try a converter that replaces single backslashes with double:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Markup;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    public class SlashConverter : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
    {
        private static SlashConverter _converter = null;
        public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            if (_converter == null)
            {
                _converter = new SlashConverter();
            }
            return _converter;
        }
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return (value.ToString()).Replace(@"\", @"\\");
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
            CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage

```
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding DownloadPath, Converter={local:SlashConverter}}"/>
```

Note that a converter as a resource might be somewhat more efficient if you use this a lot since that'd be a singleton. Try the converter, see if this solves your issue. If it does then refactor to taste.

If it doesn't then the converter has another usage.

For debug info.

Put a break point in and see what the converter is actually handed.

Comment: Thank you, but it is not working, it just adds another `î`.

Comment: The point was to narrow down the problem. It's not intended as a paste and forget solution. As I explained.

Comment: Yes, I know, thanks. I somehow have a feeling that this might be related to the keyboard language, I've tried to set `InputLanguageManager.InputLanguage="en-US"` for respective `TextBox` without any luck. Will dig further.

Comment: Or the string doesn't have what you think it has in it. Which is why I suggested you put a break point in and see what the converter is actually handed.

Comment: I just checked with my home computer and this issue is not present there. It seems that our work computers have some localization settings which interferes with the `TextBox`. It is strange because I only have en-US keyboard added in Control Panel. Might be some Active Directory settings.